Handling byte strings in robot framework returns in null or blank
I have results returned from a function and storing it in a dictionary like this
${results}={'value': b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00', 'type': None, 'error': None}
Now I want to extract only the value of the key 'value' into another variable.
When I try to access it like this :
 ${results}=    Get From Dictionary    dictionary=${results}    key=value
    Log     ${results}

OR
 ${results}= Set Variable ${results}[value]
    Log     ${results}

OR
${results}= Convert to String  ${results}[value]

I am getting only blank in the ${results} variable.
Maybe this is due to byte string . But how can I get rid of this .Can anyone help me out on this please
I need the variable ${results}= b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00'  So that I can compare it with another byte string

Taking your original line:
${results}=    Get From Dictionary    dictionary=${results}    key=value
Add the following:
${result}=    Decode Bytes To String    ${results}    encoding=ascii

You are using data has the key. Is that the correct value?
I would write:
 ${results}=    Get From Dictionary    dictionary=${results}    key='value'
 Log     ${results}

OR
 ${results}= Set Variable ${results}['value']
 Log     ${results}

OR
${results}= Convert to String  ${results}['value']


Sorry for the typo . I corrected the key that I am using . it is 'value'.
But when I tried with the quotes also This doesnt seem to work as I get this error  Dictionary '${results}' has no key ''value''.

You should Log     ${results} before trying to get the value. This way you confirm it is a dictionary with the expected structure.

Yes I am doing it .. In fact I get it like this
${results} = {'value': b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00', 'type': None, 'error': None}

Well, the binary value 0x00 has a special meaning in C language (and consequently in Python), it marks the end of a string. When trying to reproduce your problem, I got errors that the null byte cannot be in a string.
Finally, I managed to have a reproducible example for your case:
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Binary Value
    ${my_value}=    Evaluate    bytes('\\x01\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x01\\x00', 'utf-8')
    &{results}=    Create Dictionary    value=${my_value}    type=${None}    error=${None}
    Log    ${results}    console=True
    ${new_result}=    Get From Dictionary    dictionary=${results}    key=value
    Log    New result is:${new_result}    console=True

It does find the value, even if it cannot represent. The key must not have quotes.

Thank you for the response. But when I try to use the same the bytes always turns to blank and no value is added to dictionary .
${my_value} = BuiltIn . Evaluate bytes('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00', 'utf-8')
${my_value} =
KEYWORD &{actual_results} = BuiltIn . Create Dictionary value=${my_value}, type=${None}, error=${None}
INFO &{actual_results} = { value= | type=None | error=None }
KEYWORD BuiltIn . Log ${actual_results}, console=True
KEYWORD${new_result} = Collections . Get From Dictionary dictionary=${actual_results}, key=value
INFO ${new_result} =
